# Does any spin have a direction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, vectors

Does any pure spin state have a direction, that is it is an eigenstate of spin operator (in this direction)? If yes, how to prove it? In other words, suppose we have a spin state $$|S\rangle = \alpha|S_z+\rangle + \beta|S_z-\rangle.$$ Is it true that
$$\hat{S_n}|S\rangle = s|S\rangle$$ for some direction $n$? For spin 1/2 it is geometrically clear from the Bloch sphere picture.

---

PS: I expected a general answer, but if general answer is a problem, I'll accept even answer for spin 1/2 case.

Comment: Just a comment but if you want to consider an arbitrary spin s, your first equation should really read $|\psi\rangle = \sum_{m=-s}^{m=+s}\alpha_m |s,m\rangle$ ie it should be a sum of $2s+1$ states, not only 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For spin-1/2: yes.  You can verify that
$$
\cos\textstyle\frac\theta2 \vert + \rangle + e^{i\varphi}\sin\textstyle\frac\theta2\vert -\rangle\, ,
$$
which parametrizes the most general spin-1/2 state,
is an eigenstate of
$$
\hat n\cdot\vec S=n_xS_x+n_yS_y+n_zS_z \tag{1}
$$
with
$$
n_x=\sin\theta\cos\varphi\, ,\quad n_y=\sin\theta\sin\varphi\, ,\quad 
n_z=\cos\theta\ . \tag{2}
$$
Note that Eqs.(1) and (2) actually define the most general linear combination of spin operators.

For larger $S$, no in general.  Basically you only have $3$ quantities to play with: $n_x,n_y$ and $n_z$, and they depend on only two parameters: $\theta$ and $\varphi$ because of the constraint $n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2=1$.  Thus you cannot expect that you will be able to write an arbitrary vector in a large dimension space if you are looking for an eigenstate of a linear combination of at most $3$ operators depending on only two parameters.

A more formal proof uses [Wigner $D$-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix) and amounts to showing you cannot reach every final state $\vert sm\rangle$ from $\vert ss\rangle$ using rotations alone.