# Eigenvalues of spin operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, lie-algebra

I am currently referring Sakurai. He introduces spin states and operators from general arguments and experimental evidence but ad hoc introduces that the eigenvalues of the pure states as $\pm \frac{\hbar}{2}$, Is there a more foundational argument to why the eigenvalues take those values or can they be scaled arbitrarily?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is the value of spin $\pm 1/2$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20581/2451)

Answer (score 1):

Given the action of $S_\pm$, which can be constructed from $S_x$ and $S_y$, the eigenvalues of $S_z$ must differ by one $\hbar$ and there are two of them as spin matrices are $2\times 2$ matrices.  Hence the eigenvalues are $\pm\hbar/2$.  That’s a purely (Lie) algebraic argument.  The key point is that you only need to lower once from the top eigenstate to get the bottom eigenstate, so except for rescaling $\hbar$ you don’t have a lot of freedom here.

If you want quantization about an arbitrary axis, then $S_z\mapsto US_zU^{-1}$ where $U$ is a unitary $2\times 2$ matrix.  As conjugation by $U$ does not change eigenvalues, it is immediate that quantization about *any* axis (including $\hat x$ or $\hat y$) will result in only two eigenvalues: $\pm \hbar/2$.

See also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/774740/36194).